# What happens to something impacting a frictionless surface

Tags: friction

If you try to hit a frictionless surface with the hammer at a non perpendicular plane. Would there be a force transfer or something along those lines?

Comment: i think that he is asking whether any force will be acting on any object(by Newton's 3rd law opposite force will also act on another object) perpendicular to the surface or parallel to the surface or no force will act.

Answer (score 1):

When we hit a friction-less surface with a hammer, we have to bring the hammer towards the surface with a velocity. Now it is given that we are bringing the hammer at a non-perpendicular plane. Therefore the velocity will have two components : perpendicular to the surface and parallel to the surface. The velocity parallel to the surface will remain unaffected as the surface is friction-less. However the velocity perpendicular to the surface will change due to molecular repulsion at the surface (this force will always be present in spite of the surface being friction-less). If no force was to act in perpendicular direction, its velocity won't change and so it would have to pass through the surface, a contradiction, hence force will act in perpendicular direction.

So there will be a force transfer perpendicular to the surface.